# Full Text Search in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gae-eclipse-plugin

I've developing a test app using GAE/J + Objectify and now trying to query my Data with Full Text Search (assuming Full Text Search is same as queries my data with GQL).
When I go to http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/search it shows me following error:

> There are no Full Text Search indexes in the Empty namespace. You need
>   to add data programatically before you can use this tool to view and
>   edit it.

I do have some data in my database to test the search.

What should I do enable that to search my data using GQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe FTS is still under a trusted tester program (I haven't seen any official docs even for the dev environment)

You might want to try signing up here:

https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEdWcnRJUXZ2VGR3YmVsT1Q1WVB2Smc6MQ